# LGA1366 Motherboard compatiable with Xeon E5640 Quad Core CPU?

Tags: motherboard, processor, memory, pcie, compatibility

I'm looking for a motherboard that is compatible with the CPU in question, but it must be with in my $130 Budget. I'm looking for a board suitable for budget gaming.

The board must have:

- 2+ DDR3/DDR4(If Possible) DIMM Slots, which can hold at least 8GB of RAM total
- At least 1 PCI-E x16 Slot for a Graphics Card

The only one that I found is this one:- [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/EX58-Extreme-Intel-X58-Chipset-Socket-LGA-1366-Socket-B-Motherboard-Mainboard/191816962556?_trksid=p2045573.c100033.m2042&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D41451%26meid%3D5c1eaaee27fe476090a381a262cdf950%26pid%3D100033%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D4%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D272545355248), would this work?

Or is there another alternative board that I can use instead?