# AMD Radeon HD 7670 4GB vs AMD Radeon HD 7770 4GB vs AMD Radeon R7 350 4GB vs Nvidia GTX 650 4GB for Budget Gaming PC

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, pc, memory

As per my previous question([here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/lga1366-motherboard-compatiable-with-xeon-e5640-quad-core-cpu)) on a motherboard compatiable with the Xeon E5640, I'm trying to build a cheap gaming rig that is capable of playing games like ETS2 and Fallout 3/NV on decent settings.

I seem to have come to yet another crossroad. I want to include a 4GB Graphics Card in the build, but do not have the cash to splash on a GTX 1050/TI or 1060. So I did some digging around on the online stores (Amazon, Ebay, Craigslist), and I uncovered these two cards by sheer luck, both are AMD/ATI Radeon Cards, sans the one Nvidia Card.

The HD 7670 4GB - [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Computer-Game-Graphics-Video-Card-For-AMD-HD7770-4GB-GDDR5-640sp-128Bit-PCI-E-3-/263090045557?hash=item3d41638275:g:5VkAAOSwbopZQfye)

The HD 7770 4GB - [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-ATI-Radeon-HD-7670-4GB-DDR5-128Bit-PCI-Express-Video-Graphics-Card/222585441712?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIM.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D44757%26meid%3D7e96ee107ec94af7bca8570197d9b3ab%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D263090045557)

The GTX 650 4GB - [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Point-of-View-GeForce-GTX650-4GB-/222346060432?hash=item33c4dba290:g:eL8AAOSw8w1X-~El)

The R7 350 4GB - [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Computer-Gaming-Graphics-Video-Card-for-AMD-Radeon-R7-350-4GB-GDDR5-128bit-512SP-/263105119511?hash=item3d42498517:g:ITQAAOSw44BYXBFQ)

I don't plan on doing any mining with this rig in particular, and am dead set on making the best budget build.

Long story short, which of the two cards is the better option? If none of the latter is a good option, please supply me with an answer if there is another card out there within my $100 Price Range.

(Please note that any other recommendations are preferred to be in new condition)

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: I saw your other post about the motherboard. Any LGA1366 board should work. This might not end up being very "budget".  It is a good chip for what it was, but it requires old slow ram at DDR3 speeds, motherboards that aren't in production anymore, and harder to find expensive memory ( I think it has to be ECC ram, but need to verify).      How much are you thinking to spend out of pocket around this CPU for ram/mb/graphics etc..

Comment: For the whole build, minus the case and PSU(I already have these on demand), I'm looking at $390-$400 total for the whole build. I don't want to buy a pre-build "gaming" system, plus I have already purchased the E5640 from Ebay

Comment: @akaDrHouse I did some digging around on a few forums, and I saw that the E5640 can support ECC-RAM as well as standard DDR3 RAM. The only downside in terms of RAM is that the E5640 can only support DDR3-1066Mhz. Oh well, you win some and you lose some. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those 7XXX series GPUs are very very old. Don't get them. They are not as efficient, as powerful and has less compelling feature-set.
2. For $100 max, you can sometimes get the Radeon RX 460 2/4GB (got mine new for $80 from Amazon) or a GTX 1050 Ti.
3. Current prices are a little high - not sure why, but some radeons cost even more than their MSRPs. That wasn't the case few months ago. So, I would suggest waiting if you find nothing good.
4. Just checked - newegg sells the rx 460 (2GB) for $90 on their ebay site
   http://www.ebay.com/itm/SAPPHIRE-Radeon-RX-460-DirectX-12-100409-2GOC-2L-2GB-128-Bit-GDDR5-PCI-Express-3-/302207375605?hash=item465cf698f5:g:brEAAOSw-0xYe4fX

These prices come from time to time. Just be patient

Comment: Noted. Leaving the 7XXX series behind. Would the GTX 650 be a viable option?

Comment: I don't not fully understand - the GTX 650 is an old one too, from around the same time. Are you trying to get something for less than $100? 
You wrote the budget for a GPU is $100, so the ones I've mentioned are the better ones

Comment: Well I am looking for a GPU around $100. But anything south of $100 is preferable

Comment: You have to decide what you prefer more. The best for $100 are the ones I mentioned above

Comment: I think I should wait, like you said, and watch the GPU prices from here on. Either that, or I will save up my funds and go for a high end card, like a 1060 3G or 6G

Answer (score 1):

If you can swing $110, I'd get the [RX 460](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/amd-radeon-rx-460,4707.html). It does have 2GB instead of 4GB, but higher memory bandwidth and clock speed. However, it is several tiers up the chart in terms of overall performance from what you've listed. Further, be careful ordering from China/HongKong. I've been burned before.

From [GPUboss](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-RX-460-vs-Radeon-HD-7770)

[image]

If you had pick between the two you've listed, I'd go with the 7770. 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my budget is $100 max, not a dollar more. Thats one point for the HD 7770! Plus I'm looking, preferably, for a 4GB card

Comment: @GipsyD I understand. Tis a shame though.  https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125897&cm_re=GIGABYTE_Radeon_RX_460_DirectX-_-14-125-897-_-Product

Answer (score 0):

According to UserBenchmark, the relative scores of each GPU are as follows (assuming 100% is the performance of the GTX 1070):

HD 7670 - 7%

HD 7770 - 18%

GTX 650 - 11%

R7 360 - 25%

GTX 1050 - 34%

GTX 1050Ti - 38%

The R7 350 does not appear on UserBenchmark so I used the performance of the RX 360 instead.

I hope this helps you make a more informed decision.